# Should I correct for multiple comparisons after simple main effects?

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons

I had recently a discussion with a colleague and I can't figure out who is right. Suppose you run a study with two factors: A (level 1 and level 2) and B (Level 1, level 2 and level 3). You analyse the data using a repeated measure ANOVA and you observe an interaction A*B. Now, you want to know what drives the interaction. One possibility is to perform simple main effects. My colleague argues that when you perform simple main effects tests you do not need to correct for multiple comparisons. I have a different opinion. I hope that you can help me understand who is right.

Comment: If the question is what causes the interaction, wouldn't an interaction plot be more insightful than a set of significance tests?

Comment: @FransRodenburg  My question was: considering the factorial design I proposed, shouldn't somebody correct for multiple comparisons after simple main effects tests?

Comment: I read your question and thought that a large number of hypothesis testing might not necessarily help with determining the nature of the interaction. You might want to consider answering comments without sounding annoyed if you expect to be helped. A simple answer is: as soon as you perform more than one hypothesis test, the $p$-values each have their own chance of producing a false positive. Post-hoc analyses are no exception. However, once you correct for every level you compare to every other level, nothing might remain significant and you are none the wiser. Hence, why not plot instead.

Comment: "You want to know what drives the interaction" tells us you are no longer in a statistical testing framework: you are *exploring* the data.  P-values might be helpful guides to indicate what patterns may be worth testing in *future* experiments, but "correcting" them seems misplaced in this context.